# One constructor with one argument that creates two different objects

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list, stack

So I'm taking a Java class, and one of the assignments we were given involves abstract data types (ADTs). In this assignment, we're supposed to implement an ADT known as Stack through a class called LinkedStack. LinkedStack has one constructor, but in the test cases my professor provided us, a new LinkedStack object can create either a new LinkedList object or a new ArrayList object. My issue with this is that no matter how I define my argument, I still get an error saying that the argument is incompatible with the classes.

I've tried a logical test to see whether the argument was called as a LinkedList or an ArrayList, which I think is a good thing, but I can't figure out how to properly assign the argument.

I've tried setting the argument to a Stack and then casting to a LinkedStack, with a private final variable being of of type "Stack", I've also tried calling the argument as a List, but I can't seem to get rid of the errors preventing me from starting the compiling process.

This is what we start out with:

```java
interface Stack {
    public void push(Object d){

    }

    public Object pop(){

    }

    public Object peek(){

    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){

    }
}

public class ListStack implements Stack{
    public ListStack(/*argument*/){

    }
}

//Separate test case file
//example of the test cases

public void peekTest1() {
    Stack q = new ListStack(new LinkedList());
    // assertion cases follow
}

public void peekTest2() {
    Stack q = new ListStack(new ArrayList());
    // assertion cases follow
}
```

Comment: Have you tried declaring the `/* argument */` bit of the constructor as `List`?  (Both `LinkedList` and `ArrayList` implement this interface.)

Comment: @user2478398 I think I did, but I can give it another go. Maybe I just missed something my first time through

Answer (score 0):

If you look for a type that you can use for `/*argument*/`, you can do it like this:

```
public class ListStack implements Stack {
  public ListStack(List list) {
  }
  /* note that you must implement all methods from the interface */
}
```

Why use type `List`? `List` is the common interface, implemented by `LinkedList` and `ArrayList`. So you can use one of them in the constructor.

Note: You should not use raw types. `List` and the classes that implement this interface have a type parameter. When possible you should rather use something like `List<String>` or `List<T>`. But maybe, you will learn this in a later lesson.